# Angularjs ng-view does not respond

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I am playing with angularjs, and I cannot find the reason why ng-view does not work. What  am I doing wrong?

```js
var app = angular.module('Demo', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('#/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('#/contacts', {
        template: 'contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactsController'
    });
});
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
    alert('homeController');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src=""//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js""></script>
<body ng-app>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="MainContent">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<template id="about.html">
  about
</template>

<template id="contacts.html">
  contacts
</template>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues here:

- Your script source for angular-route was incorrect in the HTML portion.
- Your $routeProvider.when lines do not need '#', so I removed them.
- One of your templates used templateUrl, which was not correct. It should only be template: as you are not calling a URL.

Here is a working plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/GSoJ4sAxM8joH6zmrxjf?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute'])

// URLs should not have # in them
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/about', {
        template: 'about.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
        template: 'contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactsController'
    });
});

app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
    alert('homeController');
});

app.controller('contactsController', function ($scope) {
    alert('contactsController');
});
```